# How to change the profile of current tab in gnome from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal

If I do this

```
gnome-terminal --profile=NEW_PROFILE
```

it indeed changes to the new profile but opens a new window. But I want it to change the profile of the current tab and not pop up a new window.

If I go through GUI, as suggested in [gnome documentation](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gnome-terminal-usage.html.en)

> 1. Click on the tab of the tabbed terminal for which you want to change
>      the profile.
> 2. Choose Terminal ▸ Change Profile ▸ profilename.

it works perfectly fine.

Just wondering how come there is no command line equivalent for this.

Comment: Because say so.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What? I dint get you.

Comment: There's no command line equivalent because they didn't put one in.

Comment: Are there any workarounds/alternatives? Like, are profiles stored somewhere as `default.profile`, `NEW_PROFILE.profile` so that we can change them??